# Image loading using Glide taking too much time

Tags: android, image-processing, android-glide

I am showing list of images from server. Images may have different size and resolutions. I have observed that Image is taking time to load in Imageview.

Even in good internet network, its taking much time.

```
if (imageView != null && imageUri != null) {
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
        options.error(R.drawable.ic_payment_failed);
        options.format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565);
        options.override(500, 500);

        imageView.setImageUri(imageUri);
        Glide.with(context).asBitmap()
                .apply(options)
                .load(imageUri)
                .into(imageView.getProfilePic());
    }
}
```

I have tried lot many glide methods to improve loading speed, but no result.

And if try to load large image i.e 4-5 MB, Glide throwing Unable to load resource exception. To deal with this type of issue i have used transformation. But still no result.

I want image should display fast.

Comment: You have to resize that bitmap and then show. view glide

Comment: Which version of Glide are you using?

Comment: using 4.2.0 version

Comment: would you like to show blurr image before image loads ?

Comment: like in instagram

Comment: @Quicklearner No, I don't want show blur image. Its meaningless for me. I want to speed up loading.

Comment: @Quicklearner how to achieve blur image like Instagram?

Comment: i will share the code in sometime:)

Comment: Well, it sounds like you are trying to fix the symptom and not the problem. You should not be loading images that large if you just plan to resize them before displaying them. The user is trusting you as an app developer to be cautious with the use of their data and memory and you are abusing that trust in this scenario. I suggest you create a parameter in the API that tells it the size you need and either resize on the server before returning it (and not blocking UI) or have resized images already ready to go on the server.

Comment: do you have two urls ie one for image path and other for thumbnail path ?

Answer (score 0):

you can Use GlideApp for new version glide.

you must create a java class with this name `MyAppGlideModule` in your project. and make class like below code.

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule { 
}
```

and you can also use `OKHttp` for `glide` with add this dependence in your `Gradle`.

```
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.8.0"
```

and replace that class

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule { 
    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
       OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
       OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory factory = new  OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client);
       glide.getRegistry().replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, factory);
    }
}
```

after that `Build` your project.after you Build project. you can Use `GlideApp` instead `Glide`.like this

```
GlideApp.with(context)
     .load(myUrl)
     .placeholder(placeholder)
     .into(yourTarget);
```

you can use the latest version of glide.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

Comment: How use this class? How it will help?

Comment: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#memory-cache Total Google search time to find that link using only keywords from this question: 10 seconds... Maybe try it for yourself next time ?

Comment: @RohanPatel you can read all of that in this link 
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#memory-cache

Comment: @Alishatergholi - Thanks for sharing link. But can you help me to identity solution? If you know let me know. Otherwise there is meaning to spend time to read articles if there is no solution.